# Bluez5 Agent D-Bus api returns an empty Tuple

Tags: python, dbus, bluez

I use pydbus to access D-bus api from bluez5. I'd like to use the agent to handle pairings. Following the [reference](https://github.com/r10r/bluez/blob/master/doc/agent-api.txt) I call the RegisterAgent method like this:

```
remote_object = pydbus.SystemBus().get('org.bluez', '/org/bluez')
remote_object.RegisterAgent('/org/bluez/my_agent','DisplayOnly')
```

but how do I use it? It returns an empty Tuple.

Comment: Best way to learn is to look at the the [simple-agent test code](https://github.com/r10r/bluez/blob/master/test/simple-agent).